# Is It Possible to update any trigger in Information schema?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Is It Possible to update any trigger in Information schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better DROP the trigger and then CREATE the trigger. There is reason why there's no ALTER TRIGGER statement in MySQL.